# Clear react-datepicker on form reset in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-datepicker

I'm using react-final-form and react-datepicker. I also have a select for year. Start and end dates should be set to January 1 and December 31 of the default year. When a new year is selected I would like to reset the form, clear selected dates and input values of both datepickers and set them to January 1 and December 31 of the selected year respectively.

Here is the link to my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-clear-cxlxh.

So far, I have a custom component for react-datepicker which works with react-final-form. Start and end dates are set to January 1 and December 31 of the default year.

DatePicker component:

```
const DatePickerWrapper = props => {
  const { input, label, minDate, maxDate } = props;
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(input.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        minDate={minDate}
        maxDate={maxDate}
        onChange={value => {
          setStartDate(value);
          props.input.onChange(value);
        }}
        onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
        onFocus={props.input.onFocus}
        value={props.input.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And Field where it is used:

```
<Field
  name="startDate"
  initialValue={isoDate(minDate(values.year.value))}
  component={DatePickerWrapper}
  minDate={minDate(values.year.value)}
  maxDate={
    values.endDate ? values.endDate : maxDate(values.year.value)
  }
/>
```

Here is my component for resetting the form:

```
<Field name="year" subscription={{}}>
  {({ input: { onChange } }) => (
    <OnChange name="year">
      {value => {
        form.reset({
          ...initialValues,
          year: value
        });
      }}
    </OnChange>
  )}
</Field>
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I clear react-datepicker and its input value on form reset? There is a `clear()` [function](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/pull/1198), but I couldn't make it to work.
2. How can I then set the dates to January 1 and December 31 of the selected year? I've added `initialValue` for each field and the values of the form are updated. But the inputs' values stay the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few issues in the form.

1. You are giving initial values to you dates twice. Once at the top and then again as the props. `This is causing the render to go into infinite loop`. Have moved all the form initialization to top in object

```
const initialValues = {
  year: { value: "2019", label: "2019" },
  startDate: isoDate(minDate("2019")),
  endDate: isoDate(maxDate("2019")),
  amount: ""
};
```

2. When you are doing `form.reset` for the year, at that place you can reset the value for the start date and end date

```
form.reset({
  ...initialValues,
  year: value,
  startDate: isoDate(minDate(value.value)),
  endDate: isoDate(maxDate(value.value))
});
```

3. From the given code, I didn't see any requirement for usestate in datepicker.jsx as it seemed to be getting handled by the form. And so have removed it.

I have updated the code in the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-clear-bu460).

Have a look at it and let me know if any thing is missed or you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The value is stored in this.component_name.current.state, so use an assignment operator and assign an empty string to it. do this operation in a callback of a state change operation (either a setState or a useState). Should work. worked for me.

```
this.startdate.current.state.value = "";
this.startdate.current.state.inputValue = "";
```